# Is there a way we can cache a method or query result in GWT?

Tags: java, spring, gwt

I have a query in my GWT project which runs a filter on huge dataset for each request. The data only changes once in a day. This is causing performance issue while processing the request. Is there a framework to achieve caching of the result?

Comment: Why not create a Singleton and store the query result there?

Comment: I the result also huge? If yes - don't keep it in the client side because you will use browser's memory and could make it not responding.

Comment: I tried integrating google guava cache and it works perfectly.

Comment: A simple way is already described here - use some kind of cache. A bit more complicated is switching the servlet requests to GET for some special and cachable requests. Then you can use the browser caching mechanism. Normally you don't want, that the browser is cache GWT requests, but in some very special cases this is useful. We fetch some special resources once a day with this method.